# extract path to directory from path to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting a huge `.txt` which I need to slice, save all sliced files in a new directory which at the end of using, I delete.

Now to make a new `dir` I need path to dir. I want to save in the same `dir` given by user where he points to a `.txt` file.

```
def retPath(path):
    name = path.split('/')
    k = len(name)
    p = ""
    for i in range (0, k-1):
        if i == 0:
            p = p + name[i]
        else:
            p = p + '/' + name[i]
    return p


print(retPath('C:/dir1/dic2/file.txt'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

`C:/dir1/dic2`

This works but I wonder if there's a more pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname):

```
>>> p = '/Users/user/Desktop/words.py'
>>> os.path.dirname(p)
'/Users/user/Desktop'
```

Comment: This returns `None`. Edit: forgot to return in my function. AWESOME! thanks.